# Meaning of "get going that"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From *THE THREE-DAY BLOW* by *ERNEST HEMINGWAY*:

> "I wonder if Cards will ever win a pennant?"
>
> "Not in our lifetime," Bill said.
>
> "Gee, they'd go crazy," Nick said.
>
> "Do you remember when they **got going that** once before they had the train wreck?"

What does "got going that" mean here? If it's "got that" then it's clear to me, but when I search "got going" the meaning doesn't seem fit here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Get going that" means nothing. You are actually looking at two separate structures:

1. The phrasal verb **to get going**
2. The phrase **that once**

**Get going**, from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_going), means

> 2. (*intransitive or transitive*) To begin or commence.
>    *We'd better **get** this project **going**. If we don't **get going** on it soon, we won't finish in time.*

And **once** is a variant of **one time**, with **that** as a determiner.

So:

> when they got going that once

means

> the one [specific] time when they started [implied: *...winning a lot of games*]

Comment: In NZ at least, it's very rare for someone to use "That once" - I don't think I've ever heard or read it before other than sentences along the lines of "Just this once". Much more common is "That one time" or even just "That time"

Comment: Maybe it still exists in some pockets in the US, but at least in mainstream North American English, "That once" is also an archaic usage. "Just this once" still persists in common usage, though.

Answer (score 15):

'**got going**' means they 'started promisingly.' '**that once**' means 'that time' or 'that one and only time'.

So:

Do you remember that one time before, when Cards started promisingly and then went catastrophically wrong?